# Is there a discord server for superuser or stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

is there a discord server for superuser or stackoverflow? I can't seem to find links to any.

Comment: You know about [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=superuser.com)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't but there's an in-house [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=superuser.com)